# Non finite (..ing) v finite (..ed) verb form correct usage

Tags: creative-writing, style, technique, grammar

**The rhythm of these 3 excerpts below are different, they read to me more or less the same though. Are any actually grammatically wrong? It's funny the sort of questions that pop up when you start trying to write seriously!**

I moved in to get a closer look. ‘It is food isn’t it?’
Kay, feigning irritation, put her finger in it and flicked some at me.

I moved in to get a closer look. ‘It is food isn’t it?’
Kay feigned irritation, putting her finger in it and flicking some at me.

I moved in to get a closer look. ‘It is food isn’t it?’
Kay feigned irritation, put her finger in it and flicked some at me.

Comment: None of them is grammatically wrong, but the third one makes it sound as though 'feigning irritation' was a single action that Kay did before the other two actions, rather than an ongoing behaviour.